# Assign a value to JSON with switch statement

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON:

```
var someObj= {
    "1234": {
      "prop1": "prop1value",
      "prop2": "prop2value",
      "prop3": [ 
        "key1", 
        "key2" 
      ]
    }
}
```

I want to assign a new value to prop1.

Since I've got some more entries in that object I wanted to do it with switch statement by using a proper case number (1234 in this case).
I get to 1234 by:

```
function funct(id, prop, value) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1234:
        someObj["1234"].prop = value;
        break;
  }

  return(someObj);
}
funct(1234, prop1, "just something else")
}
```

So the function goes to object `1234` and.. adds a whole new property `prop1` with `"just something else"` assigned. I wanted it to assign `value` to `prop1`. I thought that stating `someObj["1234"].prop` would make it go to `someOjb["1234"]` and choose specified `.prop` (means `prop1` in object)

How to make it work?

Hope you get what I mean!

Comment: Are you sure it created a new property `prop1`? It should have created a new property named `.prop`.

Comment: [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), what you have there is a plain old Javascript object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
someObj["1234"][prop] = value;
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

someOjb["1234"][prop], assuming prop is the name of that field

Answer (score 0):

The property is "prop1", not `.prop`. You need to use square brackets when using dynamic properties:

```
someObj["1234"][prop] = value;
```